# Code structure when dynamically load a micro frontend via Module Federation

Tags: angular, webpack-module-federation

I picked up the git examples of https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/aktuelles/multi-framework-and-version-micro-frontends-with-module-federation-the-good-the-bad-the-ugly/ further referenced as Ex. 1 and https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/aktuelles/dynamic-module-federation-with-angular/ further referenced as Ex. 2.

Ex. 1 has multiple angular projects in it. For the sake of simplification just use the shell and the mfe1 (micro frontend 1). The example uses a `package.json` and `angular.json` for each project, which I want to use either because in the real world, we maybe have plenty of micro frontends and do not want to update all or manage all dependecies at one point. The culprit for me in this example is the fact that it uses a `WrapperComponent` and a `registry.ts`. When a route is activated it lazy loads via this function:

```js
    ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    
        const elementName = this.route.snapshot.data['elementName'];
        const importName = this.route.snapshot.data['importName'];
    
        const importFn = registry[importName];
        importFn()
          .then(_ => console.debug(`element ${elementName} loaded!`))
          .catch(err => console.error(`error loading ${elementName}:`, err));
    
        const element = document.createElement(elementName);
        this.vc.nativeElement.appendChild(element);
    
    }
```

The `registry` contains a mapping like

```js
export const registry = {
    mfe1: () => import('mfe1/web-components')
};
```

AFAIK there happens some "webpack magic" to do the import and `mfe1` is mapped to a different host via `webpack.config.js`. That means I need to know the the number and names of the micro frontends at compile time.

Ex. 2 uses a dynamic approach by using a `LookupService`

```js
export class LookupService {
    lookup(): Promise<Microfrontend[]> {
        return Promise.resolve([
            {
                // For Loading
                remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js',
                remoteName: 'mfe1',
                exposedModule: './Module',

                // For Routing
                displayName: 'Flights',
                routePath: 'flights',
                ngModuleName: 'FlightsModule'
            }
        ] as Microfrontend[]);
    }
}
```

and a function to build the routes

```js
export function buildRoutes(options: Microfrontend[]): Routes {

    const lazyRoutes: Routes = options.map(o => ({
        path: o.routePath,
        loadChildren: () => loadRemoteModule(o).then(m => m[o.ngModuleName])
    }));

    return [...APP_ROUTES, ...lazyRoutes];
}
```

Now, I want to combine both approaches. So, I copied the approach for Ex. 2 into Ex. 1 and now struggling with the following.

When simply exposing the `AppModule` of `mfe1` and dynamically load it, I have multiple `RouterModule.forRoot()` calls, which is not avoidable because `mfe1` and `shell` should also work as standalone. This leads to an error. So, I simply made a "dummy" `AppModule`, call `RouterModule.forRoot()` and have a path directing to another module, which is using only `RouterModule.forChild()` (called the `FlightsModule` in example). This other `FlightsModule` is loaded dynamically in `shell`, hence no more multiple calls to `RouterModule.forRoot()`. Is this necessary or is there another option?

Because I only can load a "submodule" of `mfe1`, I need to shift the content of several common files. `mfe1/src/styles.css` for global styles needs to be moved to a component always activated by the route with `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to make it globally accessible e.g. when using `ngx-toastr` this is needed. The `styles` option in the `angular.json` can not be used by a micro frontend because it will break when loaded over the `shell`. Everything normally imported and declared in `AppModule` needs to be shifted to the submodule. And so on...

In the end, I think this approach is definetly not the best but I tried so many different things and none, except this one, is working.

Answer (score 0):

When I was studying this, the way of the link didn't work to me and i don't remember if it's the same error as shown to you.

This is what work for me:

-------- app-shell --------
Webpack.config.js file from app-shell root folder:

```js
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    plugins: [
      new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
        configFile: './projects/app-shell/tsconfig.app.json',
      })
    ]
  },
  output: {
    uniqueName: "appShell"
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        remotes: { },
        shared: {
          "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true }, 
          "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true }, 
          "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true }
        }
    })
  ],
};
```

It points to the app-shell tsconfig.app.json.
My app-shell app-routing.module.ts file:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { loadRemoteModule } from '@angular-architects/module-federation';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'envio',
    loadChildren: () =>
      loadRemoteModule({
        remoteEntry: environment.remotes.emktConfig,
        remoteName: 'emktConfig',
        exposedModule: './Send',
      }).then((m) => m.SendModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'formularios',
    loadChildren: () =>
      loadRemoteModule({
        remoteEntry: environment.remotes.emktConfig,
        remoteName: 'emktConfig',
        exposedModule: './ConfigForms',
      }).then((m) => m.ConfigFormsModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'integracoes',
    loadChildren: () =>
      loadRemoteModule({
        remoteEntry: environment.remotes.emktConfig,
        remoteName: 'emktConfig',
        exposedModule: './Integrations',
      }).then((m) => m.IntegrationsModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'dominios',
    loadChildren: () =>
      loadRemoteModule({
        remoteEntry: environment.remotes.emktConfig,
        remoteName: 'emktConfig',
        exposedModule: './Domains',
      }).then((m) => m.DomainsModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'integracao',
    loadChildren: () =>
      loadRemoteModule({
        remoteEntry: environment.remotes.emktConfig,
        remoteName: 'emktConfig',
        exposedModule: './Integrations',
      }).then((m) => m.IntegrationsModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'conteudo',
    loadChildren: () =>
      loadRemoteModule({
        remoteEntry: environment.remotes.emktConfig,
        remoteName: 'emktConfig',
        exposedModule: './Content',
      }).then((m) => m.ContentModule),
  },
  // {
  //   path: '**',
  //   redirectTo:"/dominios"
  // },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { initialNavigation: 'enabled' })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

the var `environment.remotes.emktConfig` is a url that points to the file `remoteEntry.js` from the other project (In my case, it's inside the same folder), when developping, it's point to the port, ex:
`localhost://4201/remoteEntry.js`

-------- Other Project --------
Webpack.config.js file from other project:

```js
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  resolve:{
    plugins:[
      new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
        configFile: './projects/emkt-config/tsconfig.app.json'
      })
    ]
  },
  output: {
    uniqueName: "emktConfig",
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "emktConfig",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        "./Domains":"./projects/emkt-config/src/app/domains/domains.module.ts",
        './Content': './projects/emkt-config/src/app/content/content.module.ts',
        './Send': './projects/emkt-config/src/app/send/send.module.ts',
        './ConfigForms': './projects/emkt-config/src/app/config-forms/config-forms.module.ts',
        './Integrations': './projects/emkt-config/src/app/integrations/integrations.module.ts'
      },
      shared: {
        "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true }, 
        "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true }, 
        "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true }
      }
    })
  ],
};
```

So, here is where i expose the modules from the other project and access it in app-shell router.

app-shell:
[image]

other project:
[image]

And in the project, it is a normal Angular project:
[image]

--------- some other questions ---------

1 - For the ngx-toast, you should add it to the shared object in all webpack.config.js files, both for the shell and other projects.

1.1 - About to share imports between application, as I know, You can't do it because it's different projects, so, each project should have your own import of ngx-toast, maybe you can create a service and share that service between the projects, but i don't know if it work.

2 - About css, I have this file structure...:
[image]

In the web folder I have the main styles that is load in all projects and it is set in the angular.json to all new projects.
[image]

2.1 - Thinking difference, i only can imagine a cdn to load that file instead being builded with the project

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Basically that's the approach I described. Instead of exposing the `AppModule` you exposed the "sub modules" like `DomainModule`, `ContentModule` etc.. But what If simply want to include the whole project? Let's take your `ContentModule`: If you link that way, it could possibly be styled completly different in the shell compared to the standalone `emkt-config` project because it is missing the `styles.css` from `emkt-config`. Also you need to include every module. I just want to say "Show the complete frontend of project y in a shell project x if selected in nav".

Comment: You want to use one style and load it once?

Comment: That's not the main aspect. Like in the last comment said, I want to load a complete project `x` within the `shell`. Applying all styles, imports used by project `x` etc. E.g. `ngx-toastr` is imported with a `forRoot()` call in `AppModule` of `x`. If I just load a sub-module of `x` within `shell` it does not work. 1. Because there is an `InjectionError` for the Service provided by `ngx-toastr` since nobody is calling the `forRoot` and import it properly. 2. The global style from the project `x`'s `styles.css` main folder is not applied.

Comment: I updated the answer with more things, let me know if it's fit to you.